# Get a parameter of a file .txt using python

Tags: python, function, file, parameters, module

I'm trying to get parameters of a .txt like that:

```
a=10
b=15
c=20
```

How can i do a function called get() that takes from this file called parameters.txt the parameter b and return 15??

It's to build a module that works like a getter of parameters.

To simplify and explain information: the .txt conatains parameters with and int value. The get() function will obtain the integer value associated to the parameter.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question is unclear, e.g. what is `parameter of a file`? Please provide a **[mcve]**.

Comment: Consider using an existing data serialization module instead of writing your own file format. For example, `pickle` or `json`. Or maybe even a proper database.

Comment: Please show what you have already tried. You can read the file by lines and then use split

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you say you want "to build a module that works like a getter of parameters", you should just parse the whole file into an internal dictionary:

```
class Config(dict):
    def __init__(self, file_name):
        with open(file_name) as f:
            for line in f:
                key, value = line.strip().split("=")
                self[key] = value
```

Example usage:

```
c = Config("test.txt")
print(c)
# {'a': '10', 'b': '15', 'c': '20'}
print(c['b'])
# 15
```

If all your values are numerical, you might want to modify this to do `self[key] = float(value)` or similar. Otherwise you might want to define a `try_parse_numeric` function:

```
def try_parse_numeric(s):
    try:
        return int(s)
    except ValueError:
        pass
    try:
        return float(s)
    except ValueError:
        pass
    return s

class Config(dict):
    def __init__(self, file_name, value_parser=try_parse_numeric):
        self.value_parser = value_parser
        with open(file_name) as f:
            for line in f:
                key, value = line.strip().split("=")
                self[key] = self.value_parser(value)
```

And if it gets more complicated than that, you probably want to use [`configparser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html) instead of rolling your own.

Answer (score 1):

```
def get(param):
    with open(filename, "r") as infile:     #Read file
        for line in infile:                 #Iterate over each line
            if line.startswith(param):      #Check if line starts with input param
                return line.split("=")[1]   #Return Value
print(get("b"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def get(par):
    with open("parameters.txt",'r') as file:
        return next(e for e in file.readlines() if par in e).split("=")[1]
```

Try this

Answer (score 0):

Something like this sould work:

```
def get(filename,variable):
    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            if line[:len(variable)] == variable:
                return line.split("=")[-1]
    return None

print(get("test.txt","b"))
```

Comment: In `line.split("=")[-1]` why -1? Shouldn't it be 1?

Comment: Doesn't really make a difference

Comment: Because `[-1]` just takes the last element, because the array has just 2 elements both `[1]` and `[-1]` would work

Comment: @pasch013 damn I forgot that you can access array elements with negative indexes in python. My bad.